# Sylius grid add button to product table

Tags: sylius

How can I override product table grid to add new button next to edit and delete?

I have found: vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\AdminBundle\Resources\config\grids\product.yml

The button should open modal button with html content. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.

You could either include a config file for grid which will look more or less like this:

```
# app/config/grids.yml
sylius_grid:
    grids:
        sylius_admin_product:
           actions:
               # your new action here
```

or copy entire yaml file you've found in

```
vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\AdminBundle\Resources\config\grids\product.yml
```

into your app/Resources folder:

```
app/Resources/SyliusAdminBundle/config/grids/product.yml
```

and override what you want :)

More info can be found here: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/grid.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an example here:
[Custom template](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/views/ProductVariant/Grid/Action/updatePositions.html.twig) and [How to register](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/f6269ec3cd3dad71a058437c971ee4206fb021a1/src/Sylius/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/config/app/config.yml#L48) and [How to use](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/f6269ec3cd3dad71a058437c971ee4206fb021a1/src/Sylius/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/config/grids/product_variant.yml#L51-L52)
You can register this action in any place where you define grids. It's not necessary

```
sylius_grid:
    templates:
       filter:
          your_filter_name: @YourBundle/Path/After/Resource/_filter_name.html.twig
       action:
          # the same defining
       bulk_action:
          # the same defining
```